# On OpenBSD, how do I recompile OpenSSL with md2 support?

Tags: compiling, openbsd, openssl

I searched but couldn't find any similar questions. I need to recompile OpenSSL with md2 support so that I can compile and install libpki. I can't for the life of me figure out how recompiling OpenSSL should be done. Should I download the current sources and compile then install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to do this. For example see: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-2409

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest source, run `./Configure` with the option `enable-md2`, and then the make command:

```
./Configure enable-md2
make
```